# No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=fb://page/FACEBOOK_PAGE_ID

Tags: android

In the title FACEBBOK_PAGE_ID is an integer id of my facebook page.
In my android application, on click of button say "Fllow us on facebook", i have to redirect the application - 
1. If facebook app is installed and user logged in - redirect to the facebook page facebook app.
2. If facebook app is installed but user is not logged - redirect to the facebook login page in the facebook app.
3. If facebook app is not installed - open facebook page URL in browser.
I did this with the following code

```
@OnClick(R.id.rl_follow_us_on_fb)
    public void onClickFollowUs(){
        Intent facebookIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        String facebookUrl = getFacebookPageURL(mParentActivity);
        facebookIntent.setData(Uri.parse(facebookUrl));
        startActivity(facebookIntent);
    }
```

The function for getting facebook page url is -

```
public String getFacebookPageURL(Context context) {
        PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        try {
            PackageInfo packageInfo =context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0); 
            if (packageInfo != null) {
                if (packageInfo.applicationInfo.enabled) {
                    return "fb://page/FACEBOOK_PAGE_ID";
                } else {
                    return FACEBOOK_URL;
                }
            } else {
                return FACEBOOK_URL;
            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            return FACEBOOK_URL; //normal web url
        }
    }
```

This works fine, but app crashes when user enables the facebook app if it is disabled and clicks on button "Fllow us on facebook" with the following crash  : 
`E/UncaughtException: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=fb://page/FACEBOOK_PAGE_ID }`

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is add minimum facebook app version needed to open the facebook app. If the app version is lower than the minimum version, you can redirect it to play store for user to update it.

To get version name of another app in your application you can use

`PackageInfo packageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0);
return packageInfo.versionName;`